# Creating a interface for Apt-Get - Where start?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

### How to create a interface for Apt-Get?

Hi people,

I'm a Java programmer and a new Ubuntu user. I'm some confused about how Ubuntu works (packages, apt-get, etc.) and I hope you can help me.

I want understand how Ubuntu works (for developers) and in future I want help open-source projects and Ubuntu development. For that, I need start from some way, so I proposed a thing to myself: I will do a little interface for apt-get command in a week. I want create a software (please, don't Java) that downloads and install a software for the user, with a graphical interface. But, as a new user, I really don't know where to start. 

**Almost forget, don't want code, want instructions.**

1. How I can make a script/software that uses apt-get to download and install some software? (I need use Shell Script, a library for the language that I want develop, etc.?) What I must learn first?
2. After create this software/script, how I can create a graphical interface for this software? I heard something about "QT+", but I really don't know if I need use this.

Well, I think that's all. Hope you can help a Java programmer be introduced to open-source world :)

Comment: Please, post a answer and I'll give you the best answer.

Comment: Posted my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to get started would be to build on top of [python-apt](https://launchpad.net/python-apt/), which provides an easy to use, object oriented interface to libapt.

For Qt, there are two bindings, [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) and [Pyside](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide), which are pretty much equivalent and interchangeable (code written for the one in most cases just requires to change the imports to make it run with the other).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with gtk3(gui tool) based on c++ as it is more close to java and c for interface and you could use something like 'system' a linux function in it to execute commands of apt-get. As gtk is so called open source in which you are interested in and ubuntu depends on it mostly. All the best for interface